# Script.Net vs Nemerle

Tags: .net, scripting, dynamic-languages, static-typing, nemerle

I was looking into scripting to be incorporated into my apps. Then I bumped into [Script.Net](http://www.protsyk.com/scriptdotnet/) and [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Main_Page). I do know that they have different syntax and Nemerle supports macro but not Script.Net. But I would like to know more about their differences in terms of functionality, usage and flexibility. And which one would you recommend, why?

Thanks.

Sorry, I didn't notice Nemerle is a language by itself. The description seems like a scripting language. Thanks and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nemerle is a statically-typed language, and the word scripting can be found nowhere on the nemerle website.

If I were adding scripting to an app, I would consider using IronPython.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I am one of the developers of Nemerle. You may check out my post to see how to run dynamic  code with nemerle. [Don't wait for C# 5](http://reverseblade.blogspot.com/2009/02/dont-wait-for-c-5-use-nemerle.html)
Though nemerle is a static typed language. It doesn't fit if your ultimate goal is scripting

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean a domain specific language? I would consider creating your own DSL with boo. [link to book about it](http://www.manning.com/rahien/rahien_meapch1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed an scripting engine to your .net, it will probably depend on the language you, or your users, want to use:

Javascript: Script.NET, Jint

Python: IronPython

Python-like: Boo

Ruby: IronRuby

C#: CS-Script

Scheme: IronScheme

If you want to get a complete list of .NET and Java programming languages (some of them you can use to embed scripting support to your apps) you can visit my blog, where I talk about more or less 20 of them :)

http://carlosqt.blogspot.com/p/programming-languages.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider other choice than the 2 you have posted. The best I have found so far for .Net is : [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/). It takes me some time to get used to installed it but once it's install, it works great and you scripting use C# so no need to have 2 languages.